# Getting IDs of items that have database generated IDs

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So, I'm confused as to how you search a database with database generated IDs.

Let's say I add 100 items to my database and use the INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY. When I add a row using insert, I will get the ID of that row returned to me, but how would I be able to search that database with the ID it returns to me? Would I have to keep a different table with all the IDs and values they link to, because that seems like it makes my database useless.

I don't have much experience with databases and can't find any information on this, but I think it has something to do with indexing?

**EDIT:**

This is my datatbase helper class, InventoryDBHelper:

```
public class InventoryDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private final static String TAG = "InventoryDBHelper";

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Inventory.db";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + InventoryContract.Inventory.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                InventoryContract.Inventory._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                InventoryContract.Inventory.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT," +
                InventoryContract.Inventory.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE + " INT" + " );";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + InventoryContract.Inventory.TABLE_NAME;

public InventoryDbHelper (Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertItem(String name, int price){
    SQLiteDatabase write_db =  getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues write_values = new ContentValues();

    write_values.put(InventoryContract.Inventory.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, name);
    write_values.put(InventoryContract.Inventory.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE, price);

    write_db.insert(InventoryContract.Inventory.TABLE_NAME, null, write_values);

    return true;
}

public boolean updateItem(Integer id, String name, int price){
    SQLiteDatabase write_db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues write_values = new ContentValues();

    write_values.put(InventoryContract.Inventory.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, name);
    write_values.put(InventoryContract.Inventory.COLUMN_NAME_PRICE, price);

    write_db.update(InventoryContract.Inventory.TABLE_NAME, write_values, InventoryContract.Inventory._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{ Integer.toString(id)});

    return true;
}

public Cursor getItem(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase read_db = getReadableDatabase();

    return read_db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InventoryContract.Inventory.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE" + InventoryContract.Inventory._ID + "=?",
            new String[] {Integer.toString(id)});
}

public Cursor getAllItems(){
    SQLiteDatabase read_db = getReadableDatabase();

    return read_db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InventoryContract.Inventory.TABLE_NAME, null);
}

public Integer deleteItem(Integer id){
    SQLiteDatabase write_db = getWritableDatabase();

    return write_db.delete(InventoryContract.Inventory.TABLE_NAME,
            InventoryContract.Inventory._ID + " = ? ",
            new String[] {Integer.toString(id)});
}
```

}

Comment: With the `WHERE` clause? I don't quite understand the question...

Comment: @MuratK. So do you just use the 'WHERE' clause to search the database? What would be the point of the ID attribute then, if I can always get the row by searching?

Comment: ahhh  you are on the right track.  Make sure your id column is named _ID because then the built  in view pagers and such might actually work.  Of course you need to show some code.  Probably the database class.

Comment: I added my database helper class. I mostly just copied down what ever code I could find that worked, but my get, update, and delete all use the ID and I can't think of any way to get the ID without just having a full table of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database only has a single table, unique IDs won't seem to help you much.  They are necessary when using `CursorAdapter` for supporting SQL data in `ListView`s, so you definitely want them in your table.

Once you get more than one table, the ability to refer to a record in one table from a record in another table is vital for creating useful queries.  With unique IDs you can support *many-to-many relationships*.  Let's look at a simple example.

You are developing an app to manage a car rental business.  You understand you will need a table for cars.  Each car rented will have its own record and hence a unique ID.

You want to store data about customers, so you will have a customer table. Each customer will also have its own record and unique ID.

You might have a third table for rentals.  You want to track when a customer rented a car and lots of other information like price, insurance, etc. etc.

So if you already have a table of cars and a table of customers, it wouldn't make sense to duplicate all that data, so in the rental table you just store the ID of the car record and the ID of the customer record, along with the other information.

So say you insert new customer data and you get back the unique ID.  You can put that ID in the new rental record to associate the rental to that customer.

In relational databases, queries can *join* the data in tables to create a data set. In this way you can ask questions like:

- What customers have rented the car with this VIN before?

  `SELECT customer.name FROM customer, rental, car
       WHERE customer.id = rental.customer
       AND rental.car = car.id
       AND car.vin = 'VIN'`
- What cars has the customer with this last name rented before?

  `SELECT car.vin FROM car, rental, customer
       WHERE car.id = rental.car
       AND rental.customer = customer.id
       AND customer.last_name = 'LASTNAME'`

So when record IDs are placed in records of other tables, they allow you to ask your database a lot of different questions.

If you don't have much experience with databases, you should find some online tutorials on relational database design and usage.  Relational database design is a very interesting topic since it is so important to application design.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, would I mostly only use unique IDs when referencing data to other tables, and for single queries, it would just make sense to use the     WHERE clause?

Comment: Your users won't know the record ID so they probably won't be looking up your inventory by it.  But if you are displaying data in `ListView`s then it's a good idea to have the id as one of the columns.  Unless you're displaying the entire table in a `ListView`, you will most always be using a `WHERE` clause of some kind for example, name starts with "ST" (say they're typing in an autocomplete field) or price less than 10.  So the ID should be part of the data retrieved, even though you're not using it for the search.

Comment: the _id column is the key to making the builtin controls like listview to work with little or no modifications....